# Static resources arent loaded in thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've gone ahead and tried almost any tutorial with the hopes it wouldfix this.
I'm new to spring boot.

So I have a spring boot web application setup, but css, jscript and any other static content won't be loaded in  template. It's not a problem with the css or jscript as implementing them directly into the html file will make it work.
This (http://prntscr.com/lk6f6q) is how my project looks like. "test".js just includes a simple alert call.
Html: https://hastebin.com/ixejakiqev.xml
Pom: https://hastebin.com/vakinawuva.xml

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to solve this since a week and nothing seems to work. Am I maybe missing a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security config did not allow unverified access to the static resources.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exact issue using network tab of the browser.

[image]

and also ensure that you have a class something like below to handle static resources.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/webjars/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                        "classpath:/static/img/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/");
    }

}
```

Comment: The Analysis shows that no css or ja, etc. Is loaded. You don't need that config as spring boot does it by itself. But I still tried without any positive result!